# Datagrid WPF Как заполнить

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть ItemViewModel следующего вида:

```
public ItemViewModel(string name)
{
    ComboBoxContent = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    ComboBoxContent.Add("1");
    ComboBoxContent.Add("2");
    ComboBoxContent.Add("3");
    Name = name;
}

public ObservableCollection<string> ComboBoxContent { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

И есть ItemsViewModel:

```
public ItemsViewModel()
{
    Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();

    Items.Add(new ItemViewModel("name1"));
    Items.Add(new ItemViewModel("name2"));
    Items.Add(new ItemViewModel("name3"));
}

public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
```

Нужно заполнить DataGrid значениями из ItemViewModel. Приведу схематичный код как я себе это представляю:

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
          <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="ComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxContent}"></DataGridComboBoxColumn>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Как я должен правильно это сделать?

Comment: а что не работает?

Comment: То что при таком обращении ищется свойство не внутри коллекции Items, а в DataContext

Comment: разметка правильная, возможно у вас вообще не привязывается к Items, посмотрите в окне вывод при компиляции

Comment: Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. Да, есть ошибка. Name привязывается корректно и отображается, а с комбобоксами привязка не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `DataGridTemplateColumn` для использования `ComboBox` внутри ячейки:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxContent}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>               
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```